# Javascript Regex - Match multi-line strings (SCSS Map)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently working on a Node script which will search through a SCSS (Sass) file using regular expressions. The aim is to build an array/arrays of all variables defined and their values. These can then be compared against values documented in the project's documentation to check everything is in sync.

I have used the following regex to match single line variables:

`string.match(/\$[a-z-]+:(.*)(?=;)/)`

and

`string.match(/[$a-zA-Z-]+(?=:)/g)[0]` to extract each variable's name. However SCSS Maps and SCSS Variables with rather wordy values may spread onto multiple lines.

How can I search for a string which starts with a `$`, ends with a `;` and may be spread over multiple lines? Ideally I'd like to use multiple capture groups to return a single array with single line variables in one group and SCSS maps in another. This isn't essential though, two regexes would be fine.

Comment: You might be better off using something like [`scss-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-parser) instead of regexes.

Comment: "*I'd like to use multiple capture groups*" is not possible with JS regexp. If you want to match a substring starting from a `$` at the start of  a line up to the first `;`, use `s.match(/^\$[^;]+/gm)`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use last Node.js versions with ES2018 support, you can try [`/s` flag](http://exploringjs.com/es2018-es2019/ch_regexp-dotall-flag.html).

However, for such purposes, an appropriate parser would be better.